# How to swap Ctrl and Fn on a Lenovo Thinkpad keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap, remapping

I tried to exchange my <kbd>Fn</kbd> key with left <kbd>Control</kbd>, which didn't work.

I used the command `xev` to get the keycodes/keysym.

Afterwards I used:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 151=Control_L'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 37=XF86WakeUp'
```

But it didn't change anything.

I also couldn't create the `.Xmodmap` to change the keys there.

Did I forget anything? It didn't throw out an error.

Comment: is there a way to do this in Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Answer (score 44):

If you are using a Lenovo or Thinkpad laptop, see into BIOS/UEFI config to check whether there is a "Swap Fn and Ctrl" option in "Keyboard" section. According to the user guide, most models should have that option.

Answer (score 7):

You are probably using a Lenovo keyboard, which reports the <kbd>Fn</kbd> as `XF86WakeUp`. Normally <kbd>Fn</kbd> does not register an `xev` event at all because it is handled by the BIOS, therefore you **cannot** remap it.

The fact that it is reported as `XF86WakeUp` gives a lot of confusion, as you can see in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hotkey-setup/+bug/287428), but it is not really a bug, to quote [comment 27](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hotkey-setup/+bug/287428/comments/27) of that bug report:

> It's not really a bug. <kbd>Fn</kbd> *is* the wakeup key when the machine is suspended. If anyone wants to map it to other functions, then that's okay, but being able to do that is not universal... <kbd>Fn</kbd> on ThinkPads and LenovoPads is a magical/special key. If only generates its own code if not combined with any of the other magic (blue highlighted) key combinations and that is more of a fluke than anything.